# How important to require users to put details on About Us?

Tags: information-architecture, information, page, about

I am creating this application where business users can have a vendor page by providing details ex. services, prices, this happens only after these vendors signed up as an onboarding process. I also have this area where they can input "About Us" information, I want them to onboard right away by providing only some details that are really critical to their services like Prices and Type of Services. This application also has customers profile where they are the one who can interact with vendors to get the product or the service the user needs. I am not sure if it can affect us, the platform provider for both customers and businesses. Do I need to require these vendors or just optional having the About Us details?

Example below:
Facebook having this information as optional.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more context?

Comment: We can't really tell what your users will prefer. You should test your designs with the users.

Answer (score 1):

Well it really depends and it`s not necessarily about your business users preference, could be your need as a website owner for this or future customer needs who might only buy from businesses that have an About Us section.

You should evaluate how the "About us" part is having an effect on driving sales or increasing trust, help your site with SEO  & if you consider it effective you can still have it optional but have incentives ( telling business owners that businesses who have details on about us have a better chance of making a sell.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, what you are asking, is a question about diminishing returns. You want to sign people up to your website and you have, correctly, identified that often, asking for too much information upfront can be a barrier to getting those users to sign-up.

No one here can tell you whether the 'about us' field is required before signing up, only your users and the business requirements for the application can tell you that, the decision needs to be balanced against what that bit of data gives you, against the potential for turning people off and not getting them to join.

Comment: Thanks Darryl, you can create a vendor page only after these business person or owners have signed up

Comment: Hard to see how it is an issue then?